# How to ensure that function type passed as template argument does not modify arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

Consider this template

```
template<typename FunctionType>
void foo(FunctionType && function)
{
  Bar b;
  bar.mutateState();
  function(bar);
}
```

I want to make sure that `function` does not mutate `bar`. The following should not compile.

```
foo([](Bar &){});
```

However, both these lines should compile.

```
foo([](const Bar &){});
foo([](Bar){});
```

What techniques can be used? Simpler is better, but I would prefer template type introspection over `std::function` or function pointer signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SFINAE, you may do:

```
template<typename FunctionType>
auto foo(FunctionType && function)
-> decltype(function(std::declval<const Bar&>()), void())
{
  Bar bar;
  bar.mutateState();
  function(bar);
}
```

Comment: This is a good alternative if you want to make the requirement clear nearer to the function declaration, rather than burying it in the implementation where it could become lost or accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You could modify `foo` to call `function` with a `const` version of `bar`:

```
template<typename FunctionType>
void foo(FunctionType && function)
{
  Bar bar;
  bar.mutateState();
  auto const & c_bar = bar;
  function(c_bar);
}
```

Comment: For C++11, this is fine.   Before C++11,  `Bar const & c_bar` or `const Bar &c_bar = bar` are needed.    Not everyone can migrate to C++11.

Comment: @Peter  question.has `C++11` tag

Comment: I know, Revolver.   It also has a C++ tag.  C++ and C++11 are not synonyms.

Comment: @Peter: The question explicitly gives examples in terms of lambda functions (a C++11 feature). Besides, the idea of casting to `const Bar` is the basis of this answer, not the exact syntax used.

Comment: The question - how the caller can enforce a requirement that a function (or function object) not modify its arguments - is more general than lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method would be to use the [`as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) utility function (since C++17):

```
template<typename FunctionType>
void foo(FunctionType && function)
{
  Bar b;
  bar.mutateState();
  function(std::as_const(bar));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting I realized I could do the following

```
template<typename T>
typename std::add_const<T>::type &asConst(T &t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename FunctionType>
void Foo(FunctionType && function)
{
  Bar bar;
  bar.mutateState();
  function(asConst(bar));
}
```

Apparently this is included in `C++17`as [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const).

Answer (score 0):

You could be explicit about your type.

```
#pragma once

class Bar
{
    int a;
public:
    Bar() : a{0}
    {}
    void mutateState()
    {
        ++a;
    }
};

void foo(void(*function)(const Bar &))
{
    Bar bar;
    bar.mutateState();
    function(bar);
}

int main()
{
    foo([](const Bar &)
    {});
    foo([](Bar)
    {});
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the lambda has captured any variables (as the implicit conversion to function pointer will be disabled).

Comment: @Mankarse Ah, I did not think about that.